# Trying to pull values with parameters in angular

Tags: angular, api, postman, angular-cli

I'm trying to pass datas from "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo" to "http://localhost:4200/". In this url "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo" am trying to pass parameters as "authorisation and instance name" so my config file is

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://169.38.82.132:94",
    "secure": false,
    "Authorization": "bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh_HSjzF9KiVxuXN8qK4UqHZez4LdX7DYZOsee4h0Fq1PupKGTFEIzbjq9gjiaVOtPeoayIh212nDyHOEilH2chHeXz4pXzAb8YLC4aJZ0WAEOmq0werPUeaS5c5frXo_P3iwXFtTezCxsYRkNnrXoLOfkHJsxRGW91m19EqzQgqcY5q6jQUQRZeXB9KYpI6THLLnED7ZQDNJZgTjdcuKCb-Gmb1XHD_L_V_BDlbuaEcjH3Qx52f2wOsmtyWGGQEjRMfOFtpO3KJFFmpEIVH0WxsRl5L-eg7S21i_tuT1rDQMdapXiS",
    "InstanceName":"ORISSA",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "/": ""
    }
  },
  "logLevel": "debug"

}
```

and my service file is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeopleService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  fetchPeople(): Observable<Object>{

    return this.http.get('/GetFarmerInfo');

  };

}
```

after run npm start am getting response as "GET http://localhost:4200/GetFarmerInfo 404 (Not Found)". Is there anyother way to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Change your fetch people function to.

```
fetchPeople(): Observable<Object>{

    return this.http.get('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo');

  };
```

You have to give the exact URL of your API. 
`http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo` in your HTTP function.

**ADDING HEADERS**

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh_HSjzF9KiVxuXN8qK4UqHZez4LdX7DYZOsee4h0Fq1PupKGTFEIzbjq9gjiaVOtPeoayIh212nDyHOEilH2chHeXz4pXzAb8YLC4aJZ0WAEOmq0werPUeaS5c5frXo_P3iwXFtTezCxsYRkNnrXoLOfkHJsxRGW91m19EqzQgqcY5q6jQUQRZeXB9KYpI6THLLnED7ZQDNJZgTjdcuKCb-Gmb1XHD_L_V_BDlbuaEcjH3Qx52f2wOsmtyWGGQEjRMfOFtpO3KJFFmpEIVH0WxsRl5L-eg7S21i_tuT1rDQMdapXiS',
    'InstanceName': 'ORISSA'
});
```

Then pass headers in your function.

```
fetchPeople(): Observable<Object>{

    return this.http.get('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo', { headers: this.headers});

  };
```

I would recommend you to use [HTTP Interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for all your http request.

Try this code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh....', 'InstanceName': 'ORISSA' });
  fetchPeople() { return this.http.get('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo', { headers: this.headers }); };
}
```

Comment: Just because you have pass Authorization headers in your HTTP request.

Comment: Your headers are passing now there must be an issue. in your token or from backend side.

Comment: which means code is working fine and i need to check backend...

Comment: Yes also try your APIs with postman to identify where is the issue.

Comment: Yes, In postman it is working fine and i got the result in json format with heading and followed by json values. say for ex, am getting response in postman in this format--- `{
    "FarmerDetails": [
        {
            "FPO_Name": "MAULI MAA MAIZE MANDI PRODUCER COMPANY LIMITED",
            "FarmerCode": "ABHIM000003628/NaRaDe",
            "FarmerName": "Abhimanyu",            
        }, I guess the header ""FarmerDetails":" causes issues and if we omit this heading and load only json values it will be working fine, am i correct?

Comment: No I don't think so its a json format error. You have to check your request headers from chrome > inspect > networks > api
Check if the headers are correct in your request

Comment: Thanks @Ali Wahab, am getting response as "Message: "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."" in console under network

Comment: Try this code
`new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer uRf0e8upueR4qTh....', 'InstanceName': 'ORISSA' , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`

Comment: Thanks @Ali Wahab, getting message as "POST http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo 401 (Unauthorized)" in console

Comment: Yes, fetchPeople() { return this.http.get('http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo',.......and If am using post I got 401 unauthorised error and if am using get am getting "405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: In postman If i used get I got the same error ""Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." and If i use post the correct response is displaying.

Comment: I have to look in your code man. There must be a small thing which is causing issue

Comment: Okay Can you give me your mail ID so that I will send my code and postman API, am using 3 files only so it i easy for me to send in mail, can i send to contact@howilearnt.com

Comment: Check this Stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg6wqe

I thinks its the backend causing issues

Comment: I guess the error, the api url you have posted is json array and my response is json array inside object like `{
    "FarmerDetails": [
        {` inside json array comes, is there any other possibility to overcome this